# isCollision function in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pycharm, pygame-surface

I recently started programming in pygame and I've been wondering why doesn't my isCollision function work. You don't really have to run the code, because you will need to download the pictures to make it execute. If you can, just tell my why the isCollision function doesn't work. In the mainloop where there is a for i in range(num_of_obstacles) loop there is the if iscollision statement. If you want to see what the program does, here are all the essential files:
Btw don't rewrite the entire code pls.[image: name it rectangle.png(the first image)[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu17i.png)[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyAEn.jpg)

Don't mind the comments cause theyre in polish.
Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import math
import random

#inicjowanie pygame (to trzeba zawsze dać)
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption('Kosmiczna Przygoda')

playericon = pygame.image.load('rocket.png')
player2icon = pygame.image.load('rocket.png')

backgroundImg = pygame.image.load('1083.jpg')


num_of_obstacles = 10
obstacleImg = []

obsX = [random.randint(0, 400) for i in range(num_of_obstacles // 2)]
obs2X = [random.randint(400, 800) for i in range(num_of_obstacles // 2)]

for i in obs2X:
    obsX.append(i)

obsY = []

for i in range(num_of_obstacles):
    obstacleImg.append(pygame.image.load('rectangle.png'))


for i in range(num_of_obstacles):
    obsY.append(random.randint(50, 300))

# pierwsze koordynaty
PlayerX, PlayerY = 200, 480
Player2X, Player2Y = 500, 480





PlayerY_change, PlayerX_change = 1, 1
Player2Y_change, Player2X_change = 1, 1



def player(x,y,x2,y2):
    screen.blit(playericon, (x, y))
    screen.blit(player2icon, (x2, y2))


winFont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 64)
won1, won2 = False, False

def player1Wins():
    win_text = winFont.render('PLAYER 1 WON!',True,(255,255,255))
    screen.blit(win_text,(30,30))


def player2Wins():
    win_text = winFont.render('PLAYER 2 WON!',True,(255,255,255))
    screen.blit(win_text,(150,30))

# wzór matematyczny na odległość koordynatów dwóch punktów (sprawdzabnie czy się dotykają)
def isCollision(obsX,obsY,pX,pY):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(obsX - pX, 2) + math.pow(obsY - pY, 2))
    if distance >= 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False

running = True
won = False

while running:
    # tło (blit to rysowanie)
    screen.blit(backgroundImg, (0, 0))


    # event to wydarzenie zarejestrowane przez program
    # jeżeli klikne krzyzyk w prawym gornym rogu to program sie zamknie
    # jeżeli nacisne np strzalke w prawo to rakieta przesuwa się na ukos w prawo

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                PlayerX_change = -1
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                PlayerX_change = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                Player2X_change = -1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                Player2X_change = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                PlayerY_change = 2
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                Player2Y_change = 2
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                PlayerY2_change = 0.75
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                PlayerY_change = 0.75

    for enemy in range(num_of_obstacles):
        if won:
            screen.blit(obstacleImg[enemy], (2000, 2000))
        else:
            #if isCollision(obsX[enemy], obsY[enemy],PlayerX,PlayerY):
                #player2Wins()


            screen.blit(obstacleImg[enemy], (obsX[enemy], obsY[enemy]))

    # Granice Ekranu
    if PlayerX <= 0:
        PlayerX = 0
    elif PlayerX >= 736:
        PlayerX = 736
    if PlayerY <= 0:
        won, won1 = True, True
        PlayerY, Player2Y = 480, 480
        PlayerX, Player2X = 200, 500

    if Player2X <= 0:
        Player2X = 0
    elif Player2X >= 736:
        Player2X = 736
    if Player2Y <= 0:
        won, won2 = True, True
        PlayerY, Player2Y = 480, 480
        PlayerX, Player2X = 200, 500

    if won1:
        player1Wins()
        PlayerX_change, PlayerY_change = 0, 0
        Player2X_change, Player2Y_change = 0, 0
    if won2:
        player2Wins()
        PlayerX_change, PlayerY_change = 0, 0
        Player2X_change, Player2Y_change = 0, 0

    # Zmiana kordynatów rakiety

    PlayerX += PlayerX_change
    PlayerY -= PlayerY_change
    Player2X += Player2X_change
    Player2Y -= Player2Y_change

    player(PlayerX, PlayerY, Player2X, Player2Y)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Can you provide an example of what you expect the function to produce and what it actually produces? In general a minimum code example that we can run is a good idea. At first glance, why are you detecting a collision if the distance is GREATER than 27?

Comment: Somehow the isCollision turns true at the moment when i run the code. Also the size of obcjects that collides with the player is 27.

Comment: Also the isCollision function runs in the loop for i in range(num_of_enemies). I made it a comment.

Comment: Yeah, don't you want a collision when the distance is less than 27?

Comment: I expect the function to return True when the player is close enough(27 is the distance between the player and the center of the obstacle) to the obstacle.

Comment: It return True even tho it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should you be checking if the distance is `<= 27` rather than `>= 27`?

```py
def isCollision(obsX, obsY, pX, pY):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(obsX - pX, 2) + math.pow(obsY - pY, 2))
    return distance <= 27
```

Comment: Ok. I'm embarassed that I didn't even notice that, but thanks!